# Basic factoring?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please explain the steps involved in going from:

A: $\dfrac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} + (n + 1)^2$

to:

B: $\dfrac{(n + 1)(n(2n + 1)+ 6(n + 1))}{6}$

I understand that $(n+1)^2$ has to be multiplied by $6$ before it can be summed with the numerator of A's first expression, but since it is squared, shouldn't there be another $n+1$ in B?

Comment: (**n+1**)(n(2n+1)+6(n+1))

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this website.

Comment: Try using the distributive law on the expression in B.  You should recover $(n + 1)^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I see that you know how the first expression can be put as

$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)+6(n+1)^2}{6}$$

Since $(n+1)^2$ is just (n+1) times itself, we can write:

$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)+6(n+1)(n+1)}{6}$$

Now we have an (n+1) factor on both terms so we can factor it out:

$$\frac{(n+1) (n(2n+1)+6(n+1))}{6}$$

Which is what we are looking for. This last step is done using the distributive law: $ab+ac=a(b+c)$